# Update photos on Google Photos

Tags: photos, google-photos, geolocation, geocoding

I've uploaded all of my photos to Google Photos (~100GB). I've decided to add geocoding to photos. Is it possible to upload updated version of photos? I wouldn't like to delete all uploaded photos and upload them again.

Comment: How are you adding the geo-coding?

Comment: I plan to do it manually with a desktop app. I don't have gps track for most of my photos

Comment: I think there is an option given by Google for every photo to add geo-locations.

Comment: I haven't found any option to add geolocation. Thought it might be much better to add geolocation to original photo as it it the primary source for archiving for me.